# Picard Existence of Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**The Question:**

Consider the differential equation

$$x^2\frac{dy}{dx}+(2x-1)y = \frac{1}{1+x^2}e^{-1/x} \qquad y(a) = b$$

Define the rectangle

$$R = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:|x-a|≤h \; \text{ and } \; |y-b|≤1 \}$$

Assuming that $h>0$ is sufficiently small, for which $a$ and $b$:

(i) there is a unique solution in $R$?

(ii) there are no solutions in $R$?

(iii) there are infinitely many solutions in $R$?

---

> **Picard's Theorem:**
>
> Suppose we have the differential equation
>
> $$y'(x) = f(x,y) \qquad y(a)=b$$
>
> and define the rectangle
>
> $$R = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2:|x-a|≤h \; \text{ and } \; |y-b|≤k \}$$
>
> Then there is a unique solution in $R$ if
>
> $(P1)$ $f$ is continuous in $R$ (and hence bounded)
>
> $(P2)$ For some upperbound $M$ of $f$ in $R$, we have $Mh≤k$
>
> $(P3)$ $f$ satisfies a Lipschitz condition in $R$. That is,
>
> $$\exists \text{ constant } L \; | \; |f(x,u)-f(x,v)|≤|u-v| \qquad \forall \; (x,u), (x,v) \in R$$

---

**Question (i):**

In this case, we have $k=1$ and

$$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x^2} \bigg(\frac{1}{1+x^2}e^{-1/x} + (1-2x)y \bigg)$$

$(P1)$ $f$ is continuous as long as $x \neq 0$ in $R$. Since $h$ is as small as we like, this holds as long as $a \neq 0$ (and $h<|a|$).

$(P2)$ Start with any $h<|a|$ and obtain an upperbound $M$. As we make $h$ smaller and smaller, $M$ is still an upperbound (since the smaller interval is contained in the original one), so we can just make $h<1/M$ to satisfy $Mh≤1$.

$(P3)$ We compute the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $y$:

$$\bigg| \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \bigg| = \bigg|\frac{1-2x}{x^2} \bigg|$$

and we can always find $L$ that bounds this expression, so long as we fix a closed interval not containing $x=0$. Hence by the MVT, the Lipschitz condition is satisfied.

We conclude that the solution is unique, as long as $a \neq 0$.

---

**The Problem:**

The problem arises when I go on to do questions (ii) and (iii). I don't quite understand how you can get infinitely many solutions?

Have I done something wrong with part (i)?

Comment: A hint: Is the RHS of the original ODE defined at the initial time if you take an initial condition $y(0)=b$?

Comment: Well, I guess $e^{-1/x}$ has an essential singularity at $x=0$. So does that mean when $a=0$ there is always gonna be no solution, and under no circumstances there are infinitely many solutions?

Comment: To me, that would be too strong a conclusion: We know only that, *applying the Picard theorem*, through any $(a,b)$ with $a\ne0$ there passes precisely one integral curve of the ODE. But it could be possible that, by looking, e.g., for series solutions, we would find $b$ such that the ODE with $x(0)=b$ has infinitely many solutions. That would be, however, far beyond the scope of the Picard theorem.